# Creating new subscriptions with Bicep

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, azure-bicep

I am working on a Bicep template that allow developers to choose their environment, location and function name when deploying to pipelines for a function app with azure but I would also like them to choose 2 other different subscriptions. I have one set up and would be the default one but how do I write it in bicep etc. in order for different subscriptions that one can choose when deploying it via pipeline?

Answer (score -1):

- Here is the sample code which can be used for choosing a subscription in the Bicep template.

```
targetScope = 'subscription'
module my_rg './resourcegroup.template.bicep' = {
    name: 'rg'
    scope: resourceGroup('12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012', 'resGrp')
```

```
targetScope = 'resourceGroup'

module mod './module.bicep' = {
  name: 'test'
  scope: resourceGroup('<SUB-GUID-GOES-HERE>', '<RG-NAME-GOES-HERE')
}
```

- Here is the [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/1046) and [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/deploy-to-subscription?tabs=azure-cli#scope-to-subscription) with the related discussion.

Comment: hi there and thanks for replying.  with your sample above, could you put in a way thats more readable and understandable for me based on some of the names I will be using?    my resource group names i have is rgOuranus and rgTartarus. I have two other subs names besides the defaults called exflixi and downstream.